# VMware Fusion how to open a file on OSX with a specific VM machine

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

This problem is sending me nuts.

At the moment in my finder, .pkt files are associated to be opened with the wrong virtual machine. If I right click on a .pkt file and select Open With it says PacketTracer.exe - Wrong_windows (default). I want them to be opened and associated with my Windows XP machine.

I don't know how to change that default machine even though in the target Windows XP machine I associated all the files, even in the vmware taskbar icon in osx I associated them too with that XP machine, still no luck!

Answer (score 2):

These "proxy" applications are created by VMware Fusion and are located inside the `.vmwarevm` virtual machine bundle. Right-click your virtual machine, select *Show Package Contents* and open the *Applications* folder.

Does that folder exist? Does it contain applications? Does it contain the application you want the files to open with? Make sure in the *virtual machine settings* (`Cmd-E`) *» Applications*, you specified that you want your Windows VM to handle Mac files and web links.
[image]

---

Remember that *Open With…* selection is not permanent. Open the *Get Info* dialog, select the desired windows program and VM there, and select *Change All* afterwards to make it permanent.